# azcopy of directory failing when copying between blob storage and file share - cannot transfer to the root of a service

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azcopy

I am trying to copy an existing directory from a blob storage to a directory already existing in an azure file share via the Azure CLI in the Azure portal

I get the following error

> failed to perform copy command due to error: cannot transfer
> individual files/folders to the root of a service. Add a container or
> directory to the destination URL

What I have tried

```
azcopy copy ' https://myazurename.blob.core.windows.net/subdirectory' 'https://myazurename.file.core.windows.net/blob-mirror/subdirectory' --recursive

azcopy copy ' https://myazurename.blob.core.windows.net/subdirectory/*' 'https://myazurename.file.core.windows.net/blob-mirror/subdirectory' --recursive

azcopy copy ' https://myazurename.blob.core.windows.net/subdirectory/*' 'https://myazurename.file.core.windows.net/blob-mirror/subdirectory/*' --recursive
```

Yet everything gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

Initially I have tried the same commands and got same error:

**command:**

```
 azcopy copy "https://<storage account name>.blob.core.windows.net/<c ontainer name>/directory1/?[SAS]" "https://<storage account name>.file.core.windows.net/fileshare1/directory1/" --recursive
```

**Console:**
[image]

**Portal:**

**Blob container:**

[image]

**File share:**

[image]

After I added  **`SAS`** in both blob and file url copied files successfully from blobstorage to fileshare:

**command:**

```
  azcopy copy "https://<storage account name>.blob.core.windows.net/<c ontainer name>/directory1/?[SAS]" "https://<storage account name>.file.core.windows.net/fileshare1/directory1/?[SAS]" --recursive=true
```

**Console:**

[image]

**Portal:**

**Fileshare:**

[image]

**Update**

You can get **`SAS`** for both blob and file

Home -> storageaccount -> shared access signature -> check the allowed resource group -> click the generate SAS and Connection string.

[image]